# How to persist GWT application login on each new tab that is opened on the same browser?

Tags: gwt

I have this GWT application which login/logout to a server.

The server side is ok as it can login/logout a connection.

However I need that when the application login in with a browser, the application will stay logged in for each new instance of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the information if a user has been successfully authenticated in the http session on the server side and provide a service like

```
public boolean isAuthenticated();
```

which checks that property.

Before showing any sensitive information in the client, call that service to make sure, the current user is authenticated. I would recommend not to store login credentials in a cookie.

Comment: Hmm, yah, I have isLogin() function on the service. Problem is that I haven't implemented session in the server side.

Comment: mhm, what do you mean with, "I haven't implemented session... "? I guess you are using java on the server side. Maybe you could explain in more detail, what you try to achieve including which frameworks you use etc..

Answer (score 2):

Use cookies on the browser to store login details.  When a new tab is opened, and requests the page from the server, the cookies will be passed along automatically and you can log the user in from there.

Make sure you understand the security implications of storing login details in cookies before deploying this strategy!